# Use one column for color and an other one for legend in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I have a data frame with 5 variable as :

```
head(drop(rast.df))
  Longitude Latitude Values   Color
1 -15.10068 16.68171     32 #98d604
2 -15.08271 16.68171     32 #98d604
3 -14.99288 16.68171     32 #98d604
4 -14.97492 16.68171     32 #98d604
5 -14.95695 16.68171     32 #98d604
6 -15.11865 16.66375     32 #98d604
                                                                    Main
1 Sparse Herbaceous: dominated by herbaceous annuals (<2m) 10-60% cover.
2 Sparse Herbaceous: dominated by herbaceous annuals (<2m) 10-60% cover.
3 Sparse Herbaceous: dominated by herbaceous annuals (<2m) 10-60% cover.
4 Sparse Herbaceous: dominated by herbaceous annuals (<2m) 10-60% cover.
5 Sparse Herbaceous: dominated by herbaceous annuals (<2m) 10-60% cover.
6 Sparse Herbaceous: dominated by herbaceous annuals (<2m) 10-60% cover.
```

I would like to use the `Color` column as color definition and `Main` as labels in the legend.

I have tried

```
ggplot(rast.df)+
  geom_raster(aes(x = Longitude, y = Latitude, fill=as.factor(Values)))+
  scale_fill_manual(values=as.character(unique(rast.df$Color)), 
                       name="Experimental\nCondition",
                       breaks=unique(rast.df$Values),
                       labels=unique(rast.df$Main))
```

but it dosen't work !

I don't find the way to do it automatically and I need a clue.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reproducible example:

```
tibble(
  Longitude = 1:5,
  Latitude = 10:14,
  Color = c('red', 'green', 'blue', 'red', 'green'),
  Main = c('A', 'C', 'B', 'A', 'C')
) %>%
  arrange(Main) %.>%
  ggplot(., aes(
    x = Longitude,
    y = Latitude,
    color = Main
  )) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_manual(values = unique(.$Color))
```

You need to arrange by "Main" column to avoid colors being messed up with labels.
`%.>%` pipe is from `wrapr` package.

Comment: To elaborate on this answer: it works because `%.>%`, the dot-pipe operator, creates a new object `.` in the user's environment. The object is the four-column tibble. This is important because `scale_color_manual()` doesn't have access to the variables in the tibble that is passed to `ggplot()`. Instead, in the command `scale_color_manual(values = unique(.$Color))`, `scale_color_manual()` is accessing the value of `Color` that is stored in the new `.` variable that the dot-pipe operator has created.

Comment: I would not recommend using . as the name of data frame in answers.

Answer (score 0):

This might help.

```
ggplot( ... +
        scale_color_manual(labels = Main, values = Color) +
       ...)
```

Otherwise more code might be useful.

Comment: It seems that I' can't use directly `Main` and `Color`