# specify legend colors and labels from columns of data frame

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I have a tidy data frame. I want to use it to plot lines via `geom_line()`. The colors that each line should have are specified in one column of the data frame. The labels that each line should have are specified in another column (which is also the `group` column). With a data frame like this, what is the most efficient and least error-prone way to specify a plot that has a legend with the right colors and labels?

Here is a minimal example that does what I want:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
data(iris)
iris %>%
  mutate(
    color = recode(
      Species, 
      setosa = "red", versicolor = "green", virginica = "blue")
  ) %>%

  ggplot(aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, group = Species, color = Species)) +
  geom_line() + 
  scale_color_manual(
    values = c(setosa = "red", versicolor = "green", virginica = "blue")
  )
```

My misgiving about this approach is twofold. First, the legend isn't drawing at all on the `color` column for its colors. Second, because it isn't drawing on the `color` column, I must specify the colors a second time in the `values` argument at the end of the code block, and doing so increases the chance that I'll make a mistake when re-specifying the colors.

Of course, I could use a modified version of this approach in which I don't create a `color` column. I would then be specifying colors only once. But I would rather do it the other way around: specify the colors as a column, and  make `scale_color_manual()` draw from that column (if I must use
`scale_color_manual()` at all). Is there a way to do this?

In a [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54071816/697473), Pawel Chabros shows how to use the dot-pipe operator (`%.>%`) from the "wrapr" package to do something similar. But I don't want to use that operator, as I don't like its side effect. (It creates a new object, `.`, in the global environment.) In addition to searching SO, I've read the [ggplot2 book](https://ggplot2-book.org/), but it too doesn't speak directly to this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you just looking for `scale_color_identity`? This takes the name of the color in the column and maps it to the color aesthetic. You therefore don't need to specify the color in your ggplot call at all. However, if you want the labels to be species rather than colours, you will need to make sure that you specify the `labels` argument:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
data(iris)

iris %>%
  mutate(
    color = recode(
      Species, 
      setosa = "red", versicolor = "green", virginica = "blue")
  ) %>%

  ggplot(aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, group = Species, color = color)) +
  geom_line() + 
  scale_color_identity(name = "Species", label = unique(iris$Species),
                       guide = guide_legend())
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you - this is a good solution. But suppose that the labels were not specified in the `Species` column. Suppose instead that I create a new column, `legendLabels`. In addition, I don't save the data frame containing this new column to an object; instead, I create it "on the fly" and pipe it into `ggplot()`. Is there a way to give the `scale_color_*` functions access to this column (and to the rest of the data that has been passed to `ggplot()`)?

Comment: @user697473 the `+` operator in ggplot doesn't work that way. There is no data piped through it. These are additional objects that are added on to your base plot. If you want to be able to create a `legendLabels` column on the fly and use it in a piped fashion, you will need to wrap your whole ggplot call in curly braces and use the `.` operator. This will allow you to do `label = unique(.$legendLabels)` inside `scale_colour_identity`. Don't forget to add the `.` operator as the first argument to `ggplot` itself if you are doing this.

Comment: Thank you -- this is helpful. But it seems that, in some cases, data are piped through the `+` operator. Here is an example: `iris %>% ggplot(aes(Petal.Length, Petal.Width)) + geom_line(data = . %>% filter(Species == "virginica"))`. Why is it possible to pipe data to `geom_line()` but not to the `scale_color_*` functions?

Comment: @user697473 I'm _guessing_ it's because `geoms` inherit `data` from the main ggplot call but scale objects don't.

Comment: Thank you. That sounds right, and it's consistent with the help files (`?geom_line` and `?scale_color_manual`).